# Spark sql to check current date

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do filter in spark dataframe(scala) to check if a column is less that current day.

```
myDataFrame.filter(myDataFrame("expiry_date").lt(CurrentDate))
```

But it is throwing me the below error

```
"message": "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CurrentDate$ CurrentDate"
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
myDataFrame.filter(myDataFrame("expiry_date").lt(current_date()))
```

If you have java.util.Date then use following

```
java.util.Date currDate = new java.util.Date();
myDataFrame.filter(myDataFrame("expiry_date").lt(new java.sql.Date(currDate.getTime())))
```